# Google Chrome chrome.usb / chrome.hid locked device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hid

I have a USB HID device connected to a computer running Windows 8.1. My goal is to write a Chrome App that talks to this device and parses its input. I've tried two different approaches:

- chrome.usb.findDevices() which gives Permission denied
- chrome.hid.getDevices(), chrome.hid.connect(), chrome.hid.receive() which apparently connects to the device but no input is received by the browser

The device is a NFC reader/writer and at the moment whenever I scan something the device acts like a keyboard. I know that the OS locks HID devices for security purposes amongst others, but is there any way to allow other applications to connect to those devices (from Chrome, in this instance)?

Here is my manifest:

```
"permissions" : [
    "usb",
    "hid",
    {
        "usbDevices": [
            {
                "vendorId": 2049,
                "productId": 5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything that acts as a keyboard or mouse is explicitly prohibited from being accessible via the chrome.hid.* API, and is generally intercepted by the OS, anyway.

See the comments on the [API design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17_pq7Y7HQwErLPboavAakaMimu1tXzqxEJoXdP1cckQ/edit?pli=1#heading=h.gtsc5z15ve26) and the [Chrome USB Device](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb) docs.

Answer (score 0):

It must due to the permissions set in the manifest. Sometimes, the vendorId and the productId are mixed up, so its better to declare both as:

```
"usbDevices":[
    { "vendorId": 2049, "productId": 5 }
    { "vendorId": 5, "productId": 2049 }
]
```

Have you checked on this project? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/hid

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Already tried the HID sample app: the device is recognized, I can connect to it but there's no input.